# Can't figure out IQueryable in C #

Tags: asp.net, .net, list, visual-studio-2012, iqueryable

This is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
{
    public class Attendee
    {
        public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Later in the code I am trying to use that class but it is declared as `IEnumerable`:

```
IQueryable<Attendee> myList;
```

I need to able to manually populate it. Something like this:

```
IQueryable<Attendee> districtList = new IQueryable<Attendee>() { AtendeeId = 1, FirstName = "First Name", LastName = "Last Name" }; <- This does not work. I need example of how to add one item or more then one item.
```

I would really appreciate an example of how to populate it with some fake data manually like "Test String", "test ID" etc. myList is just a variable.

To fix it I did the following:

```
var attendees = new List<Attendee>();
// Manually Populate Attendees list

myList = attendees.AsQueriable();
```

Comment: Use a list or array (`List<Attendee>` or `Attendee[]`) to build a collection, then call `AsQueryable()` and assign the result to your variable. However, it's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish by using an `IQueryable<T>` here.

Comment: What's `myList`? How did you define that? Note that `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IQueryable<T>` is an interface, so you can't instantiate it directly.  Instead, you need to create an instance of a class that implements the interface. For example:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>(){"foo", "bar"};
IQueryable<string> myQueryable = myList.AsQueryable();
```

Note: In this example, I'm using the LINQ `AsQueryable()` method to convert from an `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e. `List<T>`) to an `IQueryable<T>`.